# How to dynamically display data in B2C sign up page with a localized String?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

So I am trying to display a query parameter in my HTML page. I have not had an issue doing this is a claim, I created this.

```
<ClaimsSchema>
  <ClaimType Id="ID">
    <DisplayName>ID</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
  </ClaimType>
</ClaimsSchema>
```

Then in my relaying party I have this,

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ID" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:ID}" />
```

and in the sign in URL we have &ID=12345

What we are trying to do is send out sign up links with a specific ID value. Then when they make it to the sign in / sign up page the join now link has that ID appended to it.

So like [www.mycompany.com/register/id=12345](http://www.mycompany.com/register/id=12345)

I have localized the strings in self asserted page.

```
  <Localization>
    <LocalizedResources Id="api.selfasserted">
    <LocalizedStrings>
     <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="disclaimer_msg_intro">Dont have an account?</LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="disclaimer_link_1_text">Join Now</LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="disclaimer_link_1_url">http://www.mycompany.com/register/id=</LocalizedString>
    </LocalizedStrings>
  </LocalizedResources>
  </Localization>
```

Is there a way to inject that claim in that link?

I know i can do this with JS... i am trying to avoid using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible to do dynamic claim resolving in localised elements function. You’re going to have to use JS.